# Validating against blank password in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rails-activerecord, bcrypt

I added password password validations to my `User` model:

```
validates :password, presence: true
validates :password, confirmation: { case_sensitive: true }
```

but then when I wanted to update other fields on `users`, those validations were rendering the transaction invalid, as `password` was not present.

Through a bit of research, I realised that I could skip those validations if `password` wasn't present:

```
validates :password, presence: true, if: :validate_password?
validates :password, confirmation: { case_sensitive: true }, if: :validate_password?


def validate_password?
  password.present? || password_confirmation.present?
end
```

However, now when I submit a blank password and password confirmation, `validate_password?` returns `false`. I don't really understand what's happening, because

`@user.update_attributes(password_reset_edit_params)` returns `true`

where

`password_reset_edit_params` is `<ActionController::Parameters {"password"=>"", "password_confirmation"=>""} permitted: true>`

but inside

```
def validate_password?
  password.present? || password_confirmation.present?
end
```

`password` and `password_confirmation` evaluate to `nil`, and my `@user` password doesn't update to an empty string.

I should mention that I'm using Bcrypt, and `@user.password` actually will always evaluate as `nil`, whereas a `password_digest` is available.

So what is the solution? Ultimately I guess my question is simply:

How can ignore password validations when I'm not attempting to submit a password, but also permit those validations upon submission of an empty string?

It occurs to me that I could add a condition in the controller that doesn't allow empty strings to be passed, but there's gotta be a neat way to fix this issue.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Remove `, if: :validate_password?` from your validation.

Comment: But then that takes me back to my first problem wherein any time I try to update an instance of `User` (with or without `password`), the validation is triggered, and if I'm trying to update a user without including a password, the validation returns an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Bcrypt and digest, you can use in your model for example

```
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 8 }, allow_blank: true
```

In this case validation will work only for setting and changing password.

If you don't change password you don't need to enter password.

Another way

```
validates :password, presence: true, on: :create
```

Comment: What I'm having difficulty with is this:

If I include `allow_blank: true`, and then a blank password is submitted like `@user.update_attributes(password: '', password_confirmation: '')`, no error will be returned. How can I return a `can't be blank` error, while also allowing updates without inclusion of password?

Comment: `allow_blank` does solve most of my problem.. I'll just have to add errors on the controller if an empty string is submitted as a password. Thanks.

Comment: See my answer below to see what I mean.

Comment: Why do you need it? Params validation and fat controller is not Rails way

Comment: It's the only way I could come up with to prevent a user from entering `password: ''` and `password_confirmation: ''`. This is the one edge case that I couldn't solve any other way.

Comment: `allow_blank` is valid for `nil` and empty string unlike `allow_nil`. You can use it

Answer (score 1):

In Rails, you are not validating the param, you are validating the model.

Do not "skip validation if the password is not present". That's the purpose of validation. Validation is meant to validate the *model*, not the params. If the model has an empty password, and the password's presence is required, it is an invalid model. Always.

> but then when I wanted to update other fields on users, those validations were rendering the transaction invalid, as password was not present.

It is not because the password is not present, it is because the instance of the User does not have a password in it. The way it should work is:

1. User is created with password and validated: `User.create(name: "Me", password: "something that isn't nil")`
2. User is updated: `User.update(name: "New name") # password is inside the model still so it is still valid`

That's how it works. If you want a user to be able to have a nil / empty password, then you should not attempt to place the presence validation in the model.

Comment: My experience contradicts your explanation. When I remove `validate_password?` and attempt to do something like:

`@user.update_attributes(first_name: 'jimmy')`

the record doesn't save, and

`@user.errors.full_messages` evaluates to

`["Password can't be blank"]`

Comment: Does the `@user` have a password? Show me the output of `p @user.password`

Comment: It's `nil` (as I explained in my initial post), but the user has a `password_digest`, and `@user.authenticate('password')` returns the desired result.

Comment: You need to remove your spaghetti validations and start from the simplest `validates_presence_of :password`. If a password *must* be present, then that is the correct validation. Full stop. If your `@user` does not have a password, they cannot exist. Simple as that. Anything else, start a new thread regarding your new issue. What you've just done in the comments is prove my point. You tried to update the attribute of a `@user` that doesn't have a password and validation failed. Perfect. We want that. Now give the `@user` a `:password` and save them. Then try to update them. That's the point.

Comment: But bcrypt doesn't store a password on the User model. It accepts a password, and optionally, a password confirmation, and creates a hashed password called a password digest.

The model includes the bcrpyt method `has_secure_password` which includes validations upon the creation of a user, but it doesn't address updating a user.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html

So is this just an inherent problem in bcrypt? If I want to update a user's password, I must submit password and password confirmation, but these two fields aren't persisted in db.

Comment: Thus, it's impossible to validate password and password confirmation in the model, correct? I think I need to instead verify that the form inputs are acceptable..

Comment: Right, but that's why you shouldn't do it the way you are doing it. That doesn't change the fact that you're missing the point of validations. To save us both some time: `has_secure_password` is the BCrypt way of validating a password. You can validate `:password` like `validates :password, allow_nil: true`, but if you don't want to allow nil, ignore that and just let BCrypt / Rails do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I'm just validating password formatting and confirmation on the User model:

```
validates :password,  confirmation: true,
                      length: {within: 6..40},
                      allow_blank: true
```

and sanitising input data against blank password / password_confirmation in the controller.

```
if password_reset_edit_params[:password].blank? || password_reset_edit_params[:password_confirmation].blank?
      @user.errors[:password] << "can't be blank" if password_reset_edit_params[:password].blank?
      @user.errors[:password_confirmation] << "can't be blank" if password_reset_edit_params[:password_confirmation].blank?
      render 'edit'
```